# Two ways of initializing a class?

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I'm having some conceptual problems about classes and I want to make sure I'm doing things in the correct way.

I'm programming in Arduino and using some libraries for my project.
Libraries implement a class that I can instantiate in my project.

For example, the Library AdafruitMotorShieldV2 implements the class Adafruit_MotorShield and in the example they instantiate the class into a variable called AFMS. Everything clear so far

```
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
```

However I came up with other libraries like, DeadReckoner, where in the example the class is instantiated as:

```
#include <DeadReckoner.h>
DeadReckoner deadReckoner(&leftTicks, &rightTicks, TICKS_PER_REV, RADIUS, LENGTH);
```

Here I'm not sure what's happening.

DeadReckoner (capital letters) is the name of the class, and of course the name of the construtor. I assume deadReckoner (underscore) is a variable where DeadReckoner is instantiated, but why the call is different than in the Adafruit library?

In other words: are this two calls equivalent?

```
DeadReckoner deadReckoner(&leftTicks, &rightTicks, TICKS_PER_REV, RADIUS, LENGTH);
DeadReckoner deadReckoner = DeadReckoner(&leftTicks, &rightTicks, TICKS_PER_REV, RADIUS, LENGTH);
```

This is the relevant code inside DeadReckoner.h if needed

```
class DeadReckoner {

public:
    DeadReckoner(volatile unsigned long *, volatile unsigned long *, unsigned long, unsigned long, int, double, double);
    // other methods of the class
}
```

Answer (score -2):

first of all you should change the label from C to C++

the first is a DeadReckoner contractor that receive some references as parameters.

the second is DeadReckoner assignment operator that receive the result of DeadReckoner contractor.
look at the h file you will find signature similar to this one: 
    DeadReckoner & DeadReckoner :: operator= ( const DeadReckoner & )

the result of the two lines will be the same but the first line make a DeadReckoner object.
while the second make a DeadReckoner object the uses the assignment operator to copy it to another DeadReckoner object.

Comment: [Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)